# Website hosted in IIS 8.5 won't show images in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: internal-server-error, iis-8.5

I ran into a bizarre issue today where I had to change the authentication on my website to pass through instead of specific user.  The website started to load after that, however, in Chrome and Firefox, no images load along with css not loading.  When I did open image in new tab, this is what I get...

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

UPDATE:

The same issue happens in IE when not using the account assigned to application pool.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it was an issue with a change in permissions. The service account we were using had been removed from the admin group on the server and placed back. Rebooting solved the issue